# upgrading magento project from Magento 2.1.12 CE to Magento 2.3.2 CE setup:upgrade doesnt work

Tags: magento2, cli, magento-upgrade

Dear Magento developers,

I am trying to to upgrade Magento 2.1.12 CE To Magento 2.3.2 CE I followed official dev docs instructions https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html until the step :

Update the database schema and data

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

it doesnt seem to work

and it always throws the error message

```
    Cache cleared successfully
    File system cleanup:
/var/www/magento2/project/generated/code/Composer
    /var/www/magento2/project/generated/code/MSP
    /var/www/magento2/project/generated/code/Magento

/var/www/magento2/project/generated/code/Thirdparty1
/var/www/magento2/project/generated/code/Thirdparty2
/var/www/magento2/project/generated/code/Symfony
The directory '/var/www/magento2/project/generated/metadata/' doesn't exist - skipping cleanup
Updating modules:
Schema creation/updates:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Declaration\SchemaBuilder::processTable() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Dto\Table, boolean returned in /var/www/magento2/project/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Declaration/SchemaBuilder.php:251
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/magento2/project/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Declaration/SchemaBuilder.php(148): Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Declaration\SchemaBuilder->processTable(Object(Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Dto\Schema), Array)
#1 /var/www/magento2/project/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/SchemaConfig.php(78): Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Declaration\SchemaBuilder->build(Object(Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Dto\Schema))
#2 /var/www/magento2/project/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/DeclarationInstaller.php(57): Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\SchemaConfig->getDeclarationConfig()
#3 /var/www/ma in /var/www/magento2/project/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Declaration/SchemaBuilder.php on line 251
```

by the way if I remove app/etc/env.php I can bypasse this erreur message in web installer wizard but after that the commande still doesnt work.

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you run composer install and composer update after upgradation ?

Comment: I did that before running the magento Commande setup:upgrade  like official dev document of magento 2.3

Comment: I can edit my question but this is what I did to by base that erreur I changed  return instruction return $schema->getTables()[$tableData['name']]; in method processTable() but after that the commande setup:upgrade  is stock in  => Module 'Magento_Catalog':
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'catalog_category_product_index_store1_store1' doesn't exist, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_category_product_index_store1_store1` (`category_id`, `product_id`, `position`, `is_parent`, `store_id`, `visibility`) SELECT `catalog_category_product_index_store1`.* ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix this probleme I had to change return statement in method

```
vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Declaration/SchemaBuilder::proccesTable()
```

using this statement

```
return $schema->getTables()[$tableData['name']];
```

and I commented out all instructions in method

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Setup/Patch/Data/EnableSegmentation::apply()
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

After Upgradation, Basically you need to do this steps such as:

```
Composer Install
```

Then you need to run

```
Composer Update
```

Then you need to set permission as

```
Chmod -R 777 /var /generated /pub
```

Then you need to set owner Group as

```
chown -R development:development .
```

Then you need to enable all the Modules or desired modules by

```
php bin/magento module:enable --all
```

Then after you need to run

```
php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento s:d:c && php bin/magento s:s:d -f && php bin/magento c:c && php bin/magento c:f
```

Please use this sequence once.

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following steps

**Step #1:**

```
composer require --dev allure-framework/allure-phpunit:~1.2.0 friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.13.0 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10 magento/magento-coding-standard:~1.0.0 magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework:~2.3.14 pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 phpunit/phpunit:~6.5.0 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 squizlabs/php_codesniffer:3.3.1 --sort-packages --no-update
```

**Step #2**

```
composer remove --dev sjparkinson/static-review fabpot/php-cs-fixer --no-update
```

**Step #3**
**Replace the autoload in composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
        "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
    },
    //...
}
```

**then try the composer update, setup:upgrade and all**

**DevDoc reference** [click here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html#specify-additional-packages)

Comment: tried both solutions but still the same error message when I try to debbug method vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Declaration/SchemaBuilder.php::processTable() Magento breaks in table catalog_category_product_index